# GitLab pipeline fails with exception: Cannot read property 'Minus' of undefined

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, unhandled-exception

Recently there has been an update to the pipeline, where we updated the docker version to 19.03, since the update every pipeline fails. The pipelines fail when they start the testing phase, without actually running the unit tests. They give the following message every time: *An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'Minus' of undefined.*

- The 'Minus' keyword has not been used in the code (It is an Angular app).
- There are no problems with the used dependencies.

Any idea what can the problem be?

Comment: Sometimes the last error makes no sense but arises due to another error earlier in the stage of the pipeline. Is something happening there?

Comment: No, this is not the case. Everything goes as usual, there are no errors before the testing stage starts. I even removed all the unit tests, to see if they were the problem, but the pipeline still fails.

Comment: Could be a dependency thing. Try removing your local node_modules folder and run npm install like in the pipeline. Do your test run well then?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem had something to do with the dependencies, specifically with the way they were installed. In the pipeline wasn't specified which version of the *build-angular* and *compiler-cli* was supposed to be installed, which caused the problem. *After specifying the version numbers explicitly the error was solved.*

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but got the same error with '@angular/animations' instead of 'Minus' running 'RUN npm ci' during Docker build. The problem occured after upgrading to Angular 15 and the apparent reason was that the new dependency versions were not installed. Calling 'npm i' once to update the versions resolved the issue.